# Why switch on String compiles into two switches

Tags: java, jvm, switch-statement, java-7, bytecode

I read [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10) on compiling switches and became interested in how switch statement on String is compiled. Here is the test method I examined (JDK1.7.0_40):

```
static int test(String i) {
    switch (i) {
        case "a":  return  -100;
        case "45b":  return  1;
        case "c":  return  2;
        default: return -1;
    }
}
```

I expect this method to be compiled into simple lookupswitch on hashCode of string, but suddenly

```
static int test(java.lang.String);
Code:
   0: aload_0
   1: astore_1
   2: iconst_m1
   3: istore_2
   4: aload_1
   5: invokevirtual #6         // Method java/lang/String.hashCode:()I
   8: lookupswitch  { // 3
                97: 44
                99: 72
             51713: 58
           default: 83
      }
  44: aload_1
  45: ldc           #7 // String a
  47: invokevirtual #8 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  50: ifeq          83
  53: iconst_0
  54: istore_2
  55: goto          83
  58: aload_1
  59: ldc           #9  // String 45b
  61: invokevirtual #8  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  64: ifeq          83
  67: iconst_1
  68: istore_2
  69: goto          83
  72: aload_1
  73: ldc           #10 // String c
  75: invokevirtual #8  // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  78: ifeq          83
  81: iconst_2
  82: istore_2
  83: iload_2
  84: tableswitch   { // 0 to 2
                 0: 112
                 1: 115
                 2: 117
           default: 119
      }
 112: bipush        -100
 114: ireturn
 115: iconst_1
 116: ireturn
 117: iconst_2
 118: ireturn
 119: iconst_m1
 120: ireturn
```

As you could see, in branches of first lookupswitch JVM is not doing the real work generating indices for subsequent tableswitch (line 84) instead.
Tableswitch should work fast so doesn't bring a lot of extra work. But anyway, what is the purpose of generating additional switch?
**Update**
I understand possibility of hashCode collisions. What I'm trying to say is that instead of subsequent tableswitch, compiler could move all the real work from subsequent tableswitch to first and then use ifeq to jump to the end of all switch branches. *So the one possible answer I see here: that in first switch compiler tries to precompute label for ifeq jump based on known number of cases, but I'm not sure that it is the only reason.*
**Update2**
As **@ericbn** suggested, I tried to compile

```
switch (i) { 
   case 97: return -100; 
   case 51713: return 1; 
   case 99: return 2; 
   default: return -1;
}
```

with i as int and compiler gave me plain lookupswitch.

Comment: Distinct String(s) can have the same hashCode due to the pigeonhole principle. I think that's why it does two switch(es).

Comment: don't you think there is just one switch? the second switch is for the conditional return.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr The second switch introduces an apparently unmotivated layer of indirection, the jumps looked up from the table could have been inserted direcly into the first switch block as `goto` targets.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I tried to modify code and don't use return statement in switch. Anyway, compiles into two switches. Also, compiles into one if I use switch on integer.

Comment: Try looking at the compiled code of a switch with int:
`switch (i) {
 case 97: return -100;
 case 51713: return 1;
 case 99: return 2;
 default: return -1;
}`, and check the generated "switches"...

Comment: @ericbn with int there is just one switch in bytecode.

Comment: @mkrakhin, so that's something you could add to your question to emphasize your arguments. It's a good question!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The cite from the [javac source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/langtools/file/41b81b3e37cd/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Lower.java#l3397):

```
         * The general approach used is to translate a single
         * string switch statement into a series of two chained
         * switch statements: the first a synthesized statement
         * switching on the argument string's hash value and
         * computing a string's position in the list of original
         * case labels, if any, followed by a second switch on the
         * computed integer value.  The second switch has the same
         * code structure as the original string switch statement
         * except that the string case labels are replaced with
         * positional integer constants starting at 0.
         *
         * The first switch statement can be thought of as an
         * inlined map from strings to their position in the case
         * label list.  An alternate implementation would use an
         * actual Map for this purpose, as done for enum switches.
         *
         * With some additional effort, it would be possible to
         * use a single switch statement on the hash code of the
         * argument, but care would need to be taken to preserve
         * the proper control flow in the presence of hash
         * collisions and other complications, such as
         * fallthroughs.  Switch statements with one or two
         * alternatives could also be specially translated into
         * if-then statements to omit the computation of the hash
         * code.
```